# Telephone pole flyer?

Tags: posters

How can I make one of those flyers that you always see stapled to a telephone pole or taped to a street lamp?  They are usually on letter paper and have a tear off phone number and/or URL at the bottom.

Also, the text is usually centered, but there isn't a center tag on the wiki.  Finally, the text of the tear off phone number should be rotated.

---

Kittens


               Free to good home


                   2 months old

---

2  |  2  |  2  |
    1  |  1  |  1  |
    2  |  2  |  2  |
    5  |  5  |  5  |
    5  |  5  |  5  |
    5  |  5  |  5  |
    1  |  1  |  1  |
    2  |  2  |  2  |
    1  |  1  |  1  |
    2  |  2  |  2  |

Comment: Related Question: [“Service offered note” with vertical info to be removed by potential customer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74949/service-offered-note-with-vertical-info-to-be-removed-by-potential-customer).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try the [stubs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/stubs) package, included in complete installs of both TeX Live and MiKTeX. Example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[addmargin]{stubs}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty} \pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\Huge Kittens

Free to good home

2 months old
\end{center}
\stubs[15]{3cm}[{\raggedright information for reverse side}]%
  {\raggedright Kittens, free to good home \\ 212-555-1212}
\end{document}
```

yields (on a two-sided document):

[image]

Comment: I am not able to download the package using the Windows Download Manager. I reach a timeout error, is there a torrent for the stubs package?

Comment: I just use a full install of TeX Live. A full MiKTeX install from a working mirror should work, too.

Comment: Thanks you Mike, it worked fine when I tried later, I don't know what the problem was - and then I forgot to mention that here. Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

Just a small addition to [Mike Renfro's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24191/telephone-pole-flyer/24193#24193). If you need a really big font, *cminch* does just that:

```
\font\maxi=cminch scaled 600

\begin{center}
        \maxi KITTENS
\end{center}
```

`cminch` is a TeX font that only has uppercase letters and in its original design it is about one inch tall. To access it, you need to give it a name (like `\maxi`) using TeX's `\font` command. As part of it you can scale the font -- here it is scaled down to 60% as `scaled 1000` refers to 100%. Once all is set up, you can use `\maxi`.

Comment: As long as you're using a vector font, you can use any size you want with `\fontsize{...}{...}\selectfont` (the first argument is the size, the second is size + space between lines, ordinarily about 20% more than the first argument). An example with Helvetica: `\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{100pt}{120pt}\selectfont KITTENS`