# "Service offered note" with vertical info to be removed by potential customer

Tags: vertical-alignment

I'm making a note in which I offer some services. I intend to put that note in libraries, shops, at schools, and so on. I'm sure you're all familiar with such a note. My question is, how do I do the bottom part of such a note, where the text flows vertically, and is divided into (like) ten columns? (In each column, you typically write phone number, email, and homepage - and then, with a pair of scissors, you make cuts to separate the columns.) Like I said, you probably already know what I'm talking about. Is there a standard way to do this, or, if not, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The `petiteannonce` package seems what you're looking for.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Telephone pole flyer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24191/telephone-pole-flyer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a series of `minipage`s for the tear off:

[image]

### Notes:

- One could use the `tabular` to draw the border as well, but `\fbox` provides an automatic separation that looks better.
- There is also [the stubs package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/stubs) as per this related question: [Telephone pole flyer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24191/telephone-pole-flyer).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {1,...,10} {%
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}{0.1\linewidth}
    \rotatebox{90}{%
        \fbox{%
            \parbox{3cm}{%
                \begin{tabular}{l@{~}l}%
                    Name:   & Foo bar \\
                    Phone:  & 555-1212 
                \end{tabular}%
            }%
        }%
    }%
    \end{minipage}%
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: As you don't seem to mind answering questions, is there a quick fix to remove the border (box) around the minipages? My LaTeX skills are limited, I can't tell if this is a property of the minipage, one of the box commands, or the table itself.

Comment: @EmanuelBerg: The boxed border is from the `\fbox`. So if you remove that (and the matching close `}`) you should get what you want.

Answer (score 6):

An example taken almost verbatim from the [`petiteannonce`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/petiteannonce) class documentation:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{petiteannonce}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\begin{document}

\petiteannonce[cols=2, count=4]%
{02 99 yy yy yy}
{%
  \tabcolsep=10pt\relax
  \petiteannonceaddtowidth{-2\tabcolsep}%
  \begin{tabular}%
    {@{}m{\petiteannoncewidth{0.5}}m{\petiteannoncewidth{0.5}}@{}}
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{\Large \dotfill Vend Baignoire enfant \dotfill }\\
    \hline\\
    Vend baignoire enfant.\newline 
    Dimensions \(\SI {80}{\centi \metre }\times \SI 
    {30}{\centi \metre }\)\newline
    Prix 20\si{~}\euro
    &
    \includegraphics[width=\petiteannoncewidth{0.5}]{ctanlion}
  \end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution with `tabular`

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{
  array,
  graphicx,
  calc,
  arydshln
}
\newbox\mycontacts
\savebox\mycontacts{%
  \rotatebox{90}{%
    \parbox[][\paperwidth/10-9\arrayrulewidth][c]{\widthof{www.emanuel-berg.de}+2em}{%
      \centering Emanuel Berg \\
      +00~123~456\,789 \\
      www.emanuel-berg.de%
    }
}
}
\newcommand*\putmycontacts{\usebox\mycontacts}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[bottom=0in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\vfill
\centering\makebox[0em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{ * { 9 } { @{} c @{} : } @{} c @{} }
    \hdashline
    \putmycontacts & \putmycontacts & \putmycontacts & \putmycontacts & \putmycontacts & \putmycontacts & \putmycontacts & \putmycontacts & \putmycontacts & \putmycontacts \\
  \end{tabular}%
}
\end{document}
```

### Output (full page)

[image: full page view]